# Error while using quotes syntax with packages babel, subcaption, and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, subcaption

While using quotes, I get the error

> `ERROR: Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.`

from

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \subcaptionbox{foo} {
    \tikz \node ["bar"] {};
  }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I must say that so far I never used that syntax even though it can be found in the pgfmanual. What I want to say is that `\tikz{\node[label=bar]  {};}` does the same and doesn't cause any issues. So perhaps you may use that instead.

Comment: Does it help if you load `babel` after loading the `babel` library?

Answer (score 1):

This is an expansion problem for material that is in the argument of a macro.

```
\newcommand{\x}[1]{#1}
\x{\tikz \node ["bar"] {};}
```

produces the same error with your collection of packages (with or without `subcaption`), where as

```
\tikz \node ["bar"] {};
```

on its own works fine.  In your case you are putting the `\tikz` code in the second argument of the `\subcaption` command.

A workaround is just to use `\node [label={bar}]` instead of `\node["bar"]` (and `\node [label={[red]bar]` instead of `\node["bar" red]`).

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \subcaptionbox{foo} {
  \tikz \node [label={bar}] {};
  }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```